# Create data in two unrelated tables simultaneously in Rails controller & form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a terminology translation app with this design:
[database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE46v.png)
Lang model is for storing language data (like En, de, Chinese..etc). 
Term model is for storing term data (like World Bank, Tesla..etc).
Translation model is for storing translation data, which associates two terms' ids from Term model as a pair of term translation.

Any two of the three models are not associated.

Now my problem is in translation#new I cannot create translation data (two new terms' ids) along with two new terms simultaneously.

Translation controller:

```html
class TranslationsController < ApplicationController
    
    def new
        @translation = Translation.new
        @term1 = Term.new
        @term2 = Term.new
        @translation.term1_id = @term1.id
        @translation.term2_id = @term2.id
    end
    
    def create
        @translatioin = Translation.new(translation_params)
        @term1 = Term.new(term_params)
        @term2 = Term.new(term_params)
        @translation.term1_id = @term1.id
        @translation.term2_id = @term2.id
        if @translation.save
            flash[:success] = "Term translation created successfully!"
            redirect_to translations_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    
    def index
        @translations = Translation.all
    end
    
    private
    def translation_params
        params.require(:translation).permit(:id, :term1_id, :term2_id)
    end
    
    def term_params
        params.require(:term).permit(:id, :lang_id, :name)
    end
end
```

new.html.erb in translation views:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Term Translation</h2>
            <%= form_for @translation do |f| %>
                <%= fields_for @term1 do |m| %>
                    <h4>Term 1</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= m.label 'Original Language' %>
                        <%= m.collection_select :lang_id, Lang.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Language"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= m.label 'Term' %>
                        <%= m.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
                <%= fields_for @term2 do |n| %>
                    <h4>Term 2</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= n.label 'Destination Language' %>
                        <%= n.collection_select :lang_id, Lang.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Language"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= n.label 'Translated Term' %>
                        <%= n.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
                
                <br>
                <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                <br>
            <% end %>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After I run the code, the result was "param is missing or the value is empty: translation".

I also found that the console message showed only one term's data was sent :
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zoV5mhJTT4ESicgMe76+KtExlSMGDR8W9lgcV1idwkrSvC77vDO1mfLK4gzTx0LPiXrlMjsw+MGpEWQ3tJiA0w==", "term"=>{"lang_id"=>"9", "name"=>"Weltbank"}, "commit"=>"Create"}

I failed to save two terms and one record of translation simultaneously. Please let me know how to modify my code.

Comment: Your params are missing `translation`, fix your form. It doesn't have any data in the `translation` part of the params, that is what the error you are getting is referring to `param is missing or the value is empty: translation`

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Thank you very much! I found that I have a typo on '@translatioin = Translation.new(translation_params)'. 
'@translation' was created successfully with no error messages. But '@term1.id' & '@term2.id' and '@translation.term1_id' & '@translation.term2_id' still cannot be created....